# Method to check if a point is in array's bounds

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, multidimensional-array

I'd like to make a method that will accept any two-dimensional array and a point and check if the point's coordinates are within the array's dimensions.

I don't understand how to pass any kind of 2d array into this method.

```
Check(<T>[,] arr, Point p)
Check(Array[,] arr, Point p)
```

Both give me different kinds of errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to make a generic method, I think you mean `Check<T>(T[,] arr, Point p)`.